# Is there a separation between the speaking and singing voice in classical singing pedagogy?

Tags: voice

I've been think lot about what classical singing pedagogy is all about. One could say that it is a lot about the sound, ie people singing with what is referred to as the laryngeal tilt. This is not what I am asking about.

I've been told by an opera singer, who is also a speech therapist which I suppose is important, that in classical pedagogy you are being taught by being told to focus on making a beautiful tone. The focus is on tone production. If I understand this persons correctly she says that one must first deal with speech issues. I took lessons from her and she told me to do both speech and singing exercises.

To me it seems that in classical pedagogy you often separate the speaking voice from the singing voice.
The teacher who also studied speech therapy besides classical singing did not like to separate between speaking and singing voice even if she said that singing and speaking can be very different.

Is there a separation between the speaking and singing voice in classical singing pedagogy?

Comment: What is meant by "classical" singing pedagogy?

Comment: There might be a difference, given e.g. speech level singing is considered something else than classical technique.